# When use foreachPartition to write data in rdd into mysql , i lost mysql connection occasionally

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, rdd, scalikejdbc

i use spark rdd to write data into mysql, the operator i use is `foreachPartition`, in the operator i set up connection pool and write data(using scalike jdbc's), then destory the pool, howerver it seems the connection pool cannot be found occasionally, the log said `Connection pool is not yet initialized. (name:'xxx)`, i've no idea why it happend

the data has been insert completely finally.But the exception comfused me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have implemeted in the same way (if java used)

```
dstream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

  rdd.foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords -> {

    Connection connection = createNewConnection();
    while (partitionOfRecords.hasNext()) {
      connection.send(partitionOfRecords.next());
    }
    connection.close();
  });
});
```

here insead of createNewConnection() method you just implement the singleton connection object pattern and leave with out closing.

```
dstream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

  rdd.foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords -> {

    Connection connection = ConnectionObject.singleTonConnection();
    while (partitionOfRecords.hasNext()) {
      connection.send(partitionOfRecords.next());
    }

  });
});
```

//single ton method should be like this

```
public class ConnectionObject (){


private static Connection=null;

public static Connection singleTonConnection(){

if(Connection !=null){

/** get new connection from spring data source or jdbc client**/

}
return Connection;

}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. But i have two question. 1. does singleTonConnection() make difference on if i get connection or not. i think it can only save some resources 2. for each partition in spark job is split into different tasks, if they are working in different threads, can they share same connection?

Comment: Here we have implemented singleton connection object , with **static** variable connection will be same for one JVM. 
So foreach partition will be executed on the same executor , i.e same JVM hence same connection will be available . Please upvote , if it makes answers.

Comment: It may save the resource for set up a connection and destory it frequently in fact. But i don't think it is the reason why the connection cannot be found in the first way you describe